# Jquery UI draggable and resizeabl issue in dynamic creation

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am making 10 draggable and resizeable boxes but only my first box is draggable and resizable.

How can I make all boxes draggable and resizeable?

#### Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).draggable().resizable();
    });
</script>

@for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header">User {{ $i }}</h3>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: An `id` must be unique, you can't have 10 elements with the same id `resizable`. Use a **css class** instead.

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of id

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".resizable").each(function(){
      $(this).draggable().resizable();
    })
  });
  </script>

  @for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
<div id="resizable{{ $i }}" class="resizable ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">User {{ $i }}</h3>
</div>
  @endfor
```

Comment: you cannot have 2 class attributes class="resizable" class="ui-widget-content" do class="ui-widget-content resizable"

Comment: I have modified answer

Comment: Here's a nice fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/deceiver/kw3kj6at/ for you to see it working. Also Haresh you don't need  $( ".resizable").each(function(){
      $(this).draggable().resizable();
    }) just use the $( ".resizable").draggable().resizable(); JQuery takes care of the rest. ;-)